# Django. Передача данных в базовый шаблон

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с проблемой передачи данных из одной модели в базовый шаблон!
Дано:

1. Имеется базовый шаблон base.html, который и наследуется всеми шаблонами. Именно в него в определенное место и нужно выводить данные из одной модели.
2. Собственно, сама модель в mainpage/models.py, которая и должна выводиться в базовый шаблон.

   ```
   class FixedPost(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Заголовок закрепленной публикации')
       content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, verbose_name="Содержание")
       cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='main_covers/', verbose_name='Файл с картинкой')

          def __str__(self):
              return self.title

          class Meta:
              verbose_name = 'закрепленная публикация'
              verbose_name_plural = 'Закрепленные публикации'
   ```

Я понимаю, что есть вариант, по которому можно в каждой вьюхе в context принудительно запихивать данные из этой модели, передавать в дочерний шаблон и он в нужном месте сам отрендерится в базовом шаблоне. Но, во-первых, мне кажется, что это явный костыль и должен быть явный метод как это сделать, во-вторых, больше половины вызовов шаблонов у меня оформлены как ListView и DetailView, было бы странно их все переделывать в функции с request...

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `context processor`, `custom template tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта статья про context processors наставила меня на путь истинный!

https://ustimov.org/posts/18/